# Characterizing when a subset of a group is a sub-group.

Tags: group-theory

Theorem: Let $G$ be a group. A subset $H$ of $G$ is a group if and only if $H$ is non-empty and $\forall a,b \in H, ab^{-1} \in H$

Proof: Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$:

1. So $H$ is a group.
2. Then it must contain an identity $e$.
3. So $H \neq \emptyset$. If $a,b \in H$ then $b^{-1} \in H$ and $ab^{-1} \in H$.

Now suppose $H \neq \emptyset $ AND $\forall a,b \in H, ab^{-1} \in H$.

1. As $H \neq \emptyset$, $\exists a \in H$ so $aa^{-1} = e \in H$. (I don't understand this part. If $a$ is in H $a^{-1}$ has to be in H).

(This is an extract from a book I'm following. The next two parts are based on this point. but I don't get this point.)

Comment: Hint: in the "now suppose" bit, $b$ can be equal to $a$.

Comment: "This is an extract from a book I'm following." What book is this?

Comment: H is not supposed to be a subgroup in this part, so there's no reason why $a^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics 7th Edition By Douglas Smith, Maurice Eggen, Richard St. Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption on $H$ is that *for all variations* of $a,b$ from $H$, the element $ab^{-1}$ is still in $H$.

Now apply it for $a=b=($this particular $a\in H)\ $ to get $e=aa^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Ok I get it. What if a = b. Then $bb^{-1} = e$ is also present.